# OpenCV, hand detection, color recognition

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project with gesture recognition and I don't know how to actually detect hand. I've read a couple tutorials, but these concepts are not very robust since they use simple thresholding. I thought maybe color recognition would be a good idea. For instance, hand in a black glove or any other distinctive color. I would be glad to hear any advice on how to implement this.

I use Python by the way.

Comment: do you know this? http://users.ics.forth.gr/~argyros/research/partialshapematching.html
with this paper: http://www.ics.forth.gr/~argyros/mypapers/2009_06_book_hci_gestures.pdf

Comment: meant this one: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885611000151

Comment: relying on color is not great for real world application because of the lighting variance. look into haar feature detection.

Comment: don't use color based thresholding. you can try Otsu's method. By this you can work with distinctive colors. I've implemented hand gesture recognition using opencv and python (it's pretty naive but you can get an idea) https://github.com/vipul-sharma20/gesture-opencv . There's also a link to the video in the description of the repo